# Two questions about eulerian and hamiltonian graphs.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-geometry, hamiltonian-path, eulerian-path

I have 2 questions in graph theory.

[image]

$\ \ \ $ $\ \ \ $ $\ \ \ $ $\ \ \ $ $\ \ \ $   $Graph\ 1$

$\ \ \ $ [image]

$\ \ \ $ $\ \ \ $ $\ \ \ $ $\ \ \ $ $\ \ \ $   $Graph\ 2$

$\ \ \ $[image]

$\ \ \ $ $\ \ \ $ $\ \ \ $ $\ \ \ $ $\ \ \ $   $Graph\ 3$

1) Let $Graph$ = $(G, E)$,  $G$ is set of vertices, $E$ is set of edges.

Let $S(Graph) := \{X\subset E|(G,E\setminus  X)$ is eulerian.

I want to find $min_{X \in S(Graph\ 1)} |X|$.

2) I want to find hamiltonian cycles in $Graph\ 2$ and $Graph\ 3$(or prove that graph is not hamiltonian).

$\ $

Tnak you for any help!

Comment: I am too lazy to look in depth, but it seems like this might be a helpful article to check out:
 http://ac.els-cdn.com/S030439750500112X/1-s2.0-S030439750500112X-main.pdf?_tid=afd0c0aa-8c0a-11e5-8785-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1447641503_00990c40d3f33ef409160faae430ba0e

Comment: For your information: A system flag was raised by the shear number of your edits - all relatively small. Many edits raise an eyebrow, because sometimes such antics are used solely to "bump" the post to the front page - and unfairly robbing other posts of their share of the time in the limelight. So don't do that often. The bounty will give the question all the attention it can. If you foresee the need for several edits, use [the sandbox](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4666/11619) while polishing up your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graph 2 isn't Hamiltonian. You can check that the graph is symmetric on interchanging the two high-degree vertices, or the vertices of any joined pair of degree-3 vertices, or any pair of the degree-4 vertices. Label the vertices of the graph 1,2,3 on the top row; 4,5, then 6,7, then 8,9.

Since the graph is symmetric on swapping vertices 2 and 9, the only way 2-9 could fail to be in the cycle is if 7-9-8 and 7-2-8 were both in the cycle. That's a problem if we want our cycle to contain nine vertices, so 2-9 is in the cycle; similarly 3-5.

Since the graph is symmetric on swapping 7 and 8, wlog 9-7 is in the cycle. Then 2-8 is in the cycle. But now we have to make the cycle hit vertex 5: either 8-5 is an edge, so 3-7 must be (and contradiction), or 7-5 is an edge (and so 3-8 is, contradiction).

---

Graph 3 isn't Hamiltonian. Label the vertices $1,2$ on the top row, then $3,4,5,6$ on the middle, then $7,8$ bottom row. Then any Hamiltonian cycle must contain 1-4-7, because vertex 4 has degree 2. What happens to vertex 3? Well, we go both in and out of vertex 3, so at least one of the edges 3-1, 3-7 is in the cycle; the whole graph is symmetric about the middle axis, so wlog 3-1 is in the cycle. That rules out 3-7 (which would close a triangle), so 3-6 is in the cycle.

Now, 1-2 can't be in the cycle because we can only use 1 once. Then 7-2 can't be in the cycle (because then the only way to leave 2 would be through 2-6, which would close the loop). That means we have to somehow enter and leave vertex 2 through just one edge.

Comment: Is Graph 1 a hamiltonian and eulerian? Tanx

Answer (score 3):

Graph 1 has six vertices of odd degree, so to make it Eulerian by deleting a set $X$ of edges, you have to delete at least three edges, to reduce those six odd degrees to even numbers.  By good fortune, the six odd-degree vertices can be paired up so that each pair is joined by an edge; delete those three edges, and you win.

In general graphs, you might not be so lucky. There might not be such a nice pairing of the odd-degree vertices. Then you'd have to delete paths (rather than single edges) joining the odd-degree vertices, and the problem would come down to choosing those paths so as to minimize their total length.

Answer (score 2):

Graph 3: Not Hamiltonian.  Look at that vertex of degree 2.  There is only one way in/out.  Now consider that vertex directly to the left of it.  Once you go in/out from that degree 2 vertex, how do you get in/out of this other one (which has degree 3)?

Comment: Is Graph 1 a hamiltonian and eulerian? Tanx.